# working with character pointers , NULL in while loop

Tags: c, pointers, null, character

I have a problem please help me

when i write   `*str != '\0`'    in while loop , the string will be on the output correctly,

but when i write    `str != NULL`    in the while loop , my string will be on the output but with grotesque characters! and i don't know why and where is the problem !

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(char* str)
{
  while (str != NULL) // *str != '\0'
  {
    printf("%c",*str);
    str++;
  }
}

int main()
{ 
  char a[12]="hello world";
  print(a);

  return 0;
}
```

output: `hello worldÉ‼r╟‼@ py@   y┘JG¢╫☺√¶@4pdÜ∙⌂Q&8¢∙⌂0√  Φ♦0√  ╨♦↓`

Comment: What do you expect instead? `str` will normally not become NULL by incrementing it.

Comment: You don't want to be comparing `str` to `NULL`, that's the pointer itself. You want to be printing while `*str` is not `'\0'` (NUL character).

Comment: The comment shows the correct way to find the end of the string, with `str` pointing to the string null -terminator. The string null-terminator is a special *character*, which is different from a null *pointer* (to a character).

Comment: As an easy way to understand pointers, take some paper and a pencil. Draw a rectangle, and divide it into squares. In each of the squares write each of the letters from the string you have (one letter per square), and at the end add a zero (for the null-terminator). Now draw an arrow to the first square, the one containing the letter `h`. Label this arrow `str`. Now pretend that you do the `str++` operation, by erasing the arrow, and redrawing it pointing to the *second* square (containing the letter `e`). This is how pointer work. [To be continued...]

Comment: [Continued] Once you get to the end of the string, it will be pointing to the null-terminator. The pointer itself isn't a null pointer, it's still pointing somewhere. This is what happens in your code. Incrementing the pointer more will just point to the "characters" after the null-terminator, it won't make the pointer itself a null pointer.

Comment: `str` is `char*`, a pointer. You want to return from `print()` when `str` points to a `0`, the end of the string. In this case `str` will not be zero, since it is pointing to something, the address of that particular byte with the `0`. Loop until `str` is `NULL` is another animal and it is not what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole explanation lies in the fact that `str` is a pointer, it contains a memory address. And you can access what is in that memory location by dereferencing it with `*str`.

So, when you use `*str != '\0'` you are comparing the character at the memory location pointed to by `str`, which is the right thing to do. And the last character of string will always be this special character `\0`. So, that code is correct.

When you do `str != NULL` however, you are asking to check the memory address itself, not its content, and there is no reason why the address would be NULL at the end of the string. It's like walking along a street, checking houses' numbers (the memory address), at some house the string ends but there are more houses along the street, just like there are more memory addresses past the memory alocated to the string, and you are trying to print the content of those memory locations, which you shouldn't because who knows what's there.

Answer (score 2):

`*str` gets the value where `str` is pointing to. `str` is the value of the pointer itself.

Example where `NULL` points at and where the pointer `str`  point at when using `str` points at the end of the string `"ABC"`

```
             NULL                           NULL pointer points to no valid value
                |
                |                      str  The str pointer points to '\0', its value isn't NULL and most likely not 0
                V                       V 
                          +---+---+---+---+
Values       No value ... | A | B | C |\0 |
in Memory                 +---+---+---+---+
                ^           ^           ^
Example         |           |           |
Address         0   ...   0x1432 ... 0x1435
```